# Find group owner or administrator using openAM rest API?

Tags: rest, openam

I am trying to find rest api which will tell me who is owner or admin of group using openAM restAPI.

Is this scenario valid by openAM?   OR it does not support any such API .I am trying to dig documents of openAM till date but no luck yet.

Can anyone suggest if there is any API.

Comment: OpenAM APIs is not considered to be a frontend to LDAP directory server. It's way more general, it could also merge identity information from different data stores. What if SAP HR is a data store (given you write an data store implementation) ... would you use OpenAM to retrieve information from that source... most likely not.

I always discourage to use OpenAM APIs (not matter which one - REST, SOAP, SDK) for identity management.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "owner" or "admin" of a group? I'm not sure if such concept really exists in LDAP.

Comment: Ok, if i had some group i should be able to see the owner of group which means who created the group etc. I understand openAM directly does not provide such functionality, but instead if you look at the defauly openDJ LDAP schema you will find the attribute "owner". Now i have added the attribute in openAM through  openAM console. Now when i create the group i can set the attribute owner.

Comment: My bad, the "groupOfNames" objectclass indeed specifies the "owner" attribute. Your solution seems appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

After going through docs in more details of openAM and looking at default openDJ schema i got to know there is attribute named **owner**. This attribute can be used for groups while creating them. But before i use this attribute i need to add to openAM through openAM console i.e configure the **DATA Store** in openAM and add the group attribute "**owner**". Now from my application through rest calls i set this "owner" attribute while creating group. SO i can see now who created the group information.

I have detail steps on this, if still anser is not clear let me know i can help here more.